Is Lego Mindstorms on-topic?
Lego Mindstorms allows one to write embedded-programing to design robots using Legos. How much of this technology is on-topic?

Yes.
If/when this site goes into public beta, the Mindstorms proposal will be closed. Everyone who followed/committed to it will then get an email inviting them to join this site and the existing Area 51 robotics proposals.

My take on it: this place is for Mindstorms questions related to building.

So this question should be considered off topic then, as it's about programming Mindstorms in non-LegOS languages: http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/190/can-i-write-programs-for-the-lego-rcx-2-0-in-java-c

And this one too: http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/168/can-i-check-and-charge-the-nxt-2-0-battery-charge-level-programmatically

I suspect that Mindstorms by itself is not large enough a community, and Lego itself might not be large enough.
I would vote for allowing it.

+1, I would also like to allow Mindstorms. While it may have it's own A51 Proposal I would think it best be merged into this one.
